# android map controls in webview or progress bar in phonegap

Tags: android, google-maps, cordova, webview

Hi i creates a app which will basically display a website in a webview there are 2 problems now.
1. the map inside webview does not display zoom controls or support pinch zoom i already searched and found that i need to enable the following 2 settings but still no luck

```
webSettings.setSupportZoom(true);

webSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true)
```

But when i use phonegap library it works fine , but the problem with phonegap is that it does not have a progress bar, and since i link a external webserver to produce the website i need to show a progress bar.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/UkjS0.jpg
webview

https://i.stack.imgur.com/690QI.jpg
phonegap

2 options 
How can i show map controls in webview ?
or can i display a progress bar in phonegap ?

Answer (score 1):

For your second question, if you just need some type of loading indicator, you can try adding the following lines to your app's onCreate():

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
super.setStringProperty("loadingDialog", "Title,Message"); // show loading spinner for app
super.setStringProperty("loadingPageDialog", "Loading page..."); //show spinner for sub-pages
```

Using phonegap (cordova) 1.5.0, this should create loading dialogs between page loads. The first line (I believe) is just used for the initial loading of your application.

I was only able to get progress bars by modifying the actual DroidGap source file and recompiling the jar.